# How do I get my Xbox 360 Controller to work with Dark Souls: Prepare to Die Edition?

Tags: pc, controllers, dark-souls

Just picked up this game today and I would much rather play it with my Xbox 360 controller. I'm having quite a bit of trouble however due to the fact that although I have my controller connected and working it does not seem to be usable in the game. Only the keyboard and mouse are recognized and I am unable to identify any options that may allow me to customize/enable a controller configuration. When I hit the home button I do get the GFWL overlay and the buttons/analog sticks are working fine in the overlay. I have also confirmed that I have the latest Microsoft Xbox 360 Accessories driver version 1.20.146.0 identifying the controller as player 1. What am I missing here?

I did also confirm that my controller was working in other games just as a sanity check.

Comment: I also just tried the game with my Logitech Gamepad F310 in X-Input mode. Not working :( Its about as basic as controllers get. Is anyone else having this sort of trouble?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a solution on the Steam game hub..(scroll to bottom) http://steamcommunity.com/app/211420/discussions/0/882959061668056366?insideModal=1

Also, a more detailed source..(tip #5)
http://segmentnext.com/2012/08/24/dark-souls-pc-crashes-low-fps-fix-controls-errors-freezes-and-gfwl-fixes/

The trick is to disable any of your devices listed as an "HID-compliant game controller". No need to uninstall. I created a system restore point JIC.

Control Panel > System > Device Manager > Human Interface Devices >> [Disable all of your devices listed as an "HID-compliant game controller"]

Remember to restore them when you're done. Quite a pain :|
All things considered, its working now and that's fine with me until its patched.

Comment: I've had this problem with other 360 controller-enabled games - they seem to just take the controller that was connected first (or was installed first or something, I don't remember too clearly) and ignore the rest. You don't have to disable the devices, you can just unplug them.

Comment: I tried unplugging all of my other devices including my keyboard and mouse. That didn't work.

Comment: Weird. Maybe they changed the way it works. I've gotten rid of my old controller so I can't test it any more though.

Comment: I think it may also have to do with the fact that i've also got a Logitech G13 and its plethora of associated device drivers.

Comment: I tried the suggestions to just reinstall the drivers but it didn't make any difference, the HID-compliant game controller devices must be disabled in device manager- also I am using a G13 as well (although it seems to be functioning even with the devices disabled)

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails just download xpadder.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail? What does xpadder do?

Answer (score 1):

Xpadder is a great idea though. Tried to remap with this tool and it worked, but my configuration didn't save for some reason :\
I found this [Xbox 360 Dark Souls preset](https://www.rewasd.com/community/config/d044a1447c728e1f22c6b586876a7502) instead, hope this will be helpful for someone!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had drivers for my Razer Nostromo installed. I uninstalled them and I was able to use my gamepad perfectly with Dark Souls. So I guess the game has problems with certain drivers (other gamepad drivers or keypad drivers).